# How to modify json data in after storing in vue data object

Tags: json, vuejs2

This is my vue code :

```
new Vue({
    el : '#root',

    data : {
        blog : []
    },

    created() {
       this.$http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
           .then(function(response) {
               // console.log(response.data)
               this.blog = response.data
           })
           .catch(function (error) {
               this.error = 'Error! Could not reach the API. ' + error
         })
   }

});
```

My html code is :

```
<div id="root" class="container">
        <ul v-for="post in blog">
            <li> {{ post.id }}  </li>
            <li>{{ post.userId }} </li>
            <li>{{ post.title }} </li>
        </ul>

    </div>
```

Now I can show every user's name just fine, but I want to modify something like if user id is 1 then the user's name will be changed into "Smith".
I tried this code:

```
mounted() {
        if (this.blog[0].userId == 1) {
                this.blog[0].userId = 'Smith'
          }
    }
```

But it shows this error :

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'userId' of undefined

If I used in method with event it works just fine! How to do this ?

After console.log(this.blog)
[image]

Also after console.log(this.blog[0].userId) I get : "1"

Comment: So your problem is not adding the name, but related with the id? Because you are getting error as the id attr is does not exist

Comment: @samayo when i tried it shows this error : 
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined` 

But if i tried it with some event handler in method then it works fine! 
Exactly I want to modify data after saving it to array!

Comment: can you do `console.log(this.blog)` ?

Comment: @samayo Would you please read the post again? I've changed and also added more info! Pardon me if I'm not understandable! Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem is that your code in `mounted()` method done before you push `response.data` in blog array. So that's why it can't read any of properties.

You can call methods after you fetch data, in `then()` callback to be sure that you have data in blog array and then call methods for working with a blog:

```
new Vue({
  el: "#vue",
  data() {
    return {
      blog: []
    };
  },
  methods: {
    changeNames() {
      if (this.blog[0].userId == 1) {
        this.blog[0].userId = "Smith";
      }
    }
  },
  created() {
    Vue.http
      .get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts")
      .then(response => {
        this.blog = response.data;
        this.changeNames();
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        this.error = "Error! Could not reach the API. " + error;
      });
  }
});
```

Here is working example: [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hu4yzLn9/4/)

Comment: I have only tried vue 1.x and I spent 20 minutes trying to figureout the solution, and I was almost sure that mounted gets executed before created, which is why this was not working ... I didn't know what `mounted()` did, since this is new function. Anyway, good answer +1

Comment: exactly thats the thing I wanted, thank u so much! :)

Comment: You're welcome. Point is that your request is asynchronous, and you need return promise so you can work with success/fails callbacks!

Comment: Btw why use `self = this`? `this` used to work just fine, is that a new change also?